# Why does a circuit with only reactive components have infinite Q factor?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, resistance, inductor, frequency

So I came across the statement in my textbook. So I have been trying to understand why this is the case, however I just have not been able to understand

Comment: Do you know the equation for Q factor?

Comment: Resonant frequency over bandwidth

Comment: The equation that uses energy and power. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor

Comment: The definition is the same in the wiki

Comment: Don't stop reading as soon as you recognize something. Keep reading.

Comment: It can also be given as energy stored/energy loss

Comment: Exactly. No resistance = no loss

Comment: I got it, thank you.

Comment: Ideal L,C components are lossless and do not exist but ωL= XL inductors. When XL(f)+XC(f) =0 Ohms you have infinite Q

Comment: which statement are you referring to? ...the title of your post is a question, not a statement ...the two sentences in the body of your post are statements

Comment: This would be a very interesting question if you asked it with better detail. Not quite worth giving a +1 :)